# Is group $G$ must abelian, when some condition is given by using exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose we are given the following exact sequence of groups where $A$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$:

$$1 \rightarrow A \rightarrow G \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 1\tag{E}$$

If $G$ is Abelian, then $Q$ is abelian and the action $Q \curvearrowright A$ induced by the sequence $(E)$ is trivial.

Now, is converse true?

P.S: The action $Q \curvearrowright A$ induced by $(E)$ means

$Q \times A \rightarrow A: (s,a) \mapsto sas^{-1}$

which is well defined if $A$ is abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Q \curvearrowright A$ is trivial means the conjugate action $G \curvearrowright A$ is trivial. Thus $A$ lies in the center of $G$. Note also that this is also sufficient to guarantee your conditions. So in the reverse direction, we can only coclude that $A\leqslant Z(G)$, but not that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: That doesn't imply that $G$ is abelian, just that $A$ is in the centre of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yeah, you are right. I've corrected it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The dihedral group of order $8$ with $A=Z(G)$ is a nonaeblian example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes (with the right notion of converse). Given the exact sequence with

- $A$ abelian
- $Q$ abelian
- the sequence splits
- the action induced is trivial

then $G$ is abelian. In fact, the split sequence makes $G$ a semidirect product, and if the action is trivial it is the direct product.

Comment: But (s)he didn't say that the sequence splits, so surely the answer to the question  asked is no?